# Issue while loading data from API - URL - Kettle Pentaho

Tags: xml, api, kettle

I am facing some issues while downloading data from API. So there is API URL which if I manually open in a browser gives me data in a proper XML format an XML file. But I don't want to download the file, save it and then load it but instead I am looking to directly get the data and store in a table. I am using Kettle to load this data using "Get data from XML" in the transformation. All I do, is provide a link to that URL and store the output in the database table. But in this case, sometimes the URL/API response is slow and my task errors out if the page loading fails in the first attempt.

I was looking for, if possible -

1. Extend the timeout for the API to load
2. Introduce retries to the system so that even if it fails for the first time it can try again say after an interval of 5 seconds. Is there a way to do that instead of run the kettle from batch and then adding a loop interval time in batch instead of Kettle?

Error in the logs -

```
2014/08/08 05:30:04 - Purchase Sat ETL - Loading transformation from
XML file [file:///C:/Scripts/Kettle/Purchase Sat ETL.ktr] 2014/08/08
05:30:04 - Purchase Sat ETL - Dispatching started for transformation
[Purchase Sat ETL] 2014/08/08 05:30:05 - Table output.0 - Connected to
database [nav_st_copa_site_intercept] (commit=1000) 2014/08/08
05:30:05 - Generate Rows.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=1,
U=0, E=0) 2014/08/08 05:30:05 - Set field value to a constant.0 -
Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0) 2014/08/08 05:32:08
- Get data from XML.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Unexpected Error :
org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:  2014/08/08 05:32:08 -
Get data from XML.0 - org.dom4j.DocumentException: Server returned
HTTP response code: 500 for URL: <URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46
Nested exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
<URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46 2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data
from XML.0 - Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
<URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46 Nested exception: Server returned
HTTP response code: 500 for URL: <URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 - ERROR (version
5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:  2014/08/08 05:32:08 -
Get data from XML.0 - org.dom4j.DocumentException: Server returned
HTTP response code: 500 for URL: <URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46
Nested exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
<URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46 2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data
from XML.0 - Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
<URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46 Nested exception: Server returned
HTTP response code: 500 for URL: <URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -  2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get
data from XML.0 -   at
org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.getxmldata.GetXMLData.setDocument(GetXMLData.java:184)
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -     at
org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.getxmldata.GetXMLData.ReadNextString(GetXMLData.java:409)
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -     at
org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.getxmldata.GetXMLData.getXMLRowPutRowWithErrorhandling(GetXMLData.java:712)
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -     at
org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.getxmldata.GetXMLData.getXMLRow(GetXMLData.java:698)
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -     at
org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.getxmldata.GetXMLData.processRow(GetXMLData.java:655)
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -     at
org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:60) 2014/08/08
05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -    at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data
from XML.0 - Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Server returned
HTTP response code: 500 for URL: <URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46
Nested exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
<URL>StartDate=2014-07-30%2001:44:46 2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data
from XML.0 -    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -     at
org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:291) 2014/08/08 05:32:08 -
Get data from XML.0 -   at
org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.getxmldata.GetXMLData.setDocument(GetXMLData.java:162)
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 -     ... 6 more 2014/08/08
05:32:08 - Get data from XML.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1,
W=0, U=0, E=1) 2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Purchase Sat ETL - ERROR (version
5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Errors detected! 2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Purchase Sat ETL - Purchase Sat ETL
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Purchase Sat ETL - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable,
build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2014/08/08 05:32:08 - Purchase Sat ETL - Purchase Sat ETL
```

Comment: Interestingly, some other related functionality in Kettle seems to have the opposite problem: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-6459.

Comment: Look also at this: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-7779. This seems to suggest that the experienced "timeout" may actually be a deliberate action of the answering server in which case your point 1 would not help at all. What is the actual error message that you are getting?

Comment: Thank you guys for taking time and commenting here. Here is the log for the error I get (posted in the question above itself). I have purposefully out <URL> here since it contains the username and password for a secured site.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem here is with the API you are calling. A HTTP response code is 500: The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request. Thus the timeout is not necessary as the server is responding to the request giving back a response. This seems to be similar to your error, possibly check the solution? [link](https://issues.openbravo.com/view.php?id=9248&history=1#history). The API your requesting information from, can you check the server logs to see if the server is experiencing any problems?

Comment: Hi Mark, Thank you for your response. So when this happens I did not notice anything weird with the system/server logs. The network connections has been good throughout and it happens inconsistently with the API that sometimes we are able to get the response without failure where as sometime it fails and we re-run it and it succeeds. This made me think for the looping pattern for the API call. Nevertheless, since the transmission is interrupted on a non-consistent basis, we are not able to confirm is it happening from the client side or our.